# Controlling for continuous variable in linear-mixed-effect model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset `df` describing repeated scores (variable = **V5**) for each subject (coded in **V1**). Subjects belong to different groups (variable = **V7**), and have different age (variable = **V6**). The dataset is composed of 6 variables:

**V1**: categorical variable, representing subject ID 
**V2**: continuous variable 
**V4**: factor with 75 levels 
**V5**: dependent variable 
**V6**: continuous variable (age) 
**V7**: factor with two levels (groups)

I am fitting a linear mixed effect model in **R** from the `nlme` package (`lme()` function).

My goal is to estimate the effect of **V7** and **V4** and their interaction in predicting **V5**. I am using the linear mixed effect model to add **V1** as random effect with the following syntax: 
`my_lme = lme(V5 ~ V4*V7, data=df, random = ~ 1 | V1, na.action=na.omit)`

However, I am interested in **first of all regressing out the effect of V6** before applying the linear mixed effect model. Which is the most reasonable approach to do so? Would be ok to:

- First, regressing out **V6** from **V5** by applying a linear model, *e.g.* 
  `my_lm = lm(V5 ~ V6, data = df)`
- Then apply the linear mixed effect model on the `my_lm$residuals` after putting them on my dataset naming them as **V9**, hence: 
  `my_lme = lme(V9 ~ V4*V7, data=df, random = ~ 1 | V1, na.action=na.omit)`

Is this a correct approach in your expert opinion? I am sort of a newby.

I have a **second** question: 
If I then want to additionally estimate the effect of the continuous variable **V2** on the prediction of **V5** in my model, would the following syntax be correct? 
`my_lme = lme(V9 ~ V4*V7 + V2, data=df, random = ~ 1 | V1, na.action=na.omit)`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Why not just include V6 in your model with V4, V7 & V1? To address your second question, you could do this for V2 as well. 2) And are you sure you want to estimate the effects of 75 levels, not to mention their interaction with something else? If so, I hope you have a large dataset.

Comment: @mkt: 1) do you mean something as: `my_lme = lme(V5 ~ V4*V7 + V6, data=df, random = ~ 1 | V1, na.action=na.omit)`? If so, would this correct for **V6** in analysing the effect of the other variables (_i.e._ **V4** and **V7**)? With _correct_ I mean regressing out **V6**. Sorry I am a complete newby on this.  
2) Yes, I think my dataset allow for this, I have more than 10k observations.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Another issue is also: should I correct for age (**V6**) if I have already indicated subject ID (**V1**) as random effect?

Comment: 1) Yes, that's close to what I meant, except including V2 as well. lme(V5 ~ V4*V7 + V6 + V2). This is not the simplest model, and I would recommend that you read more about linear models so you understand exactly what each of those parameters is doing. Think carefully about main effects, interactions and random effects 2) I suggest doing some sort of power analysis in any case.

Answer (score 3):

Turning my comments into an answer.

To estimate the parameters you're interested in, there's no need to fit models, extract residuals and run new models. It's easier and better to specify all of the terms together in one model:

```
#Using lme4 instead of nlme here because I'm more familiar with the syntax
library(lme4)
lmer(V5 ~ V4 * V7 + V6 + V2 + (1|V1))
```

However, based on your questions I would recommend that you read more about linear models (and mixed models in particular) so you understand exactly what each of those parameters is doing. For example, your question about `age` and `subject ID` is hard to answer unless we know more about `subject ID`. I've assumed that individual subjects were measured multiple times; if so, the model above should work well (though you could consider whether random slopes are also needed). If individuals were measured only once, then you don't need a random effect at all and the model would simply be:

```
lm(V5 ~ V4 * V7 + V6 + V2)
```

Perhaps more importantly, this is assuming no nonlinearity in the effect of any of the continuous parameters. If there are such nonlinearities, you will need to modify the model.